# How to access only records where relation to other table is available - Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, inner-join, has-many-through

Let me first show you the tables

```
users_table    
id | name

businesses_table
id | user_id | name

forsale_table
id | business_id | title
```

So Im using Laravel and to get user's businesses we have to write:

```
public function businesses() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Business');
    }
```

And the business can have relation to forsale table, to access it we have to write:

```
public function sale() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Sale');
    }
```

but how to access only these businesses where for sale advert is available?

@Edit:
I managed to do this:

```
public function sale() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Sale', 'App\Models\Business');
}
```

It works pretty well, but it overrides my description, how can i access both advert description and business description

Answer (score 0):

A much I understand your requirement, you can arrange your query like mentioned method.

```
$businesses = Business::whereHas('sale', function($query)
{
    $query->where( // insert where clause here );
})->get();
```

Or you can also try

```
$Users = Users::whereHas('businesses', function($query)
{
    $query->whereHas('sale', function($query)
    {
        $query->where( // insert where clause here );
    });
})
->get();
```

Please let me know if it's help, and also let me know if something missed as per your requirement.